# How can I use CMYK values to white balance skin?

Tags: photoshop, white-balance, cmyk, skin-tones

I recently heard a photographer mention that they:

> ...adjusted the white balance using the CMYK method

I did a bit of searching on this and found different resources claiming to use formulas such as `C+M+Y = 5 * K` or that you need to have a certain percentage of each to have proper skin tones.

I'm more familiar with simply adjusting the white balance in Adobe Lightroom using the dropper tool on a grey or neutral part of the image. How would I adjust the white balance by the CMYK method properly in Photoshop(I am assuming you can't use this method in Lightroom)?

Answer (score 10):

The guide I've always used is below.  It differs by ethnicity, but is a good starting point.  You can't use a dropper tool directly on skin because it's obviously not grey.  Not if your subject is healthy

[How to get pleasing skin tone](http://help.smugmug.com/customer/portal/articles/93363)

Highlights of the article:

- % of yellow should at least equal the % of magenta.
- Light skinned subjects should have between 5-20% more yellow than magenta
- Dark skinned subjects should have yellow and magenta very close
- Cyan should be between 30% and 50% of the magenta value

The article also describes how to use curves to sample and correct the color balance.

Comment: That appears to be a very useful and complete guide. Thank you Mike!

Comment: Could you maybe summarize the link a little bit? I don't have high confidence that an article with a URL in the form ".../customer/portal/articles/93363" will be located at that location after the next site redesign.

Comment: Good idea. I've been using it for 2-3 years I'd guess, but point taken.