# How to correct skin tone using Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, color-correction, overexposure, skin-tones

How could I correct on Photoshop the skin tone to match the skin tone below?

[image: GOOD]

Starting from this overexposed picture:
[image: BAD EXPOSURE]

Comment: Why starting from an overexposed picture? Why not taking a properly exposed picture?

Comment: Bad planning during the shooting

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41928/how-can-i-use-cmyk-values-to-white-balance-skin

http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61887/how-do-you-make-a-skin-tone-metallic-brown

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to "eyeball" this color balance and exposure in Photoshop using:

> Menu >Image >Adjustments >Curves
>   Levels
>   Color Balance

A good understanding of all the commands under >Image >Adjustments is imperative to do this kind of color correction. What ever color space you are using; CMYK or RGB , it is important that you get your colors to track (black, grey and white balance) over the entire exposure latitude.